# Install Plugin jar in Grails Project?

Tags: java, maven, grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I have a grails plugin project and want to make a jar which I then include into my grails project.

Here is the plugin project: https://github.com/ticketbis/grails-groobalize

I did:

```
grails package-plugin --binary
```

To get the file: `grails-plugin-groobalize-0.1.12.jar`.

In my grails project's BuildConfig.groovy I did:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.ticketbis:groobalize:0.1.12"
}
```

When I run grails refresh-dependencies I get the following error:

```
Error |
There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates :groobalize:0.1.12, expected format is <groupId>:<artifactId>[:<extension>[:<classifier>]]:<version> (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

**How do I install the locale plugin jar into ma grails project correctly?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

You can use the release plugin: https://grails.org/plugin/release

- Add this plugin to your grails plugin and then do a publish. The plugin will then be added to your local maven repo.
- The you could add the dependency in your main grails project as you
  have already done.

---

Other way around is to checkout the plugin project, include the location in your main grails project like below.

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.plugin.location.'your-plugin' = "<location-your-plugin>"
```

This line will compile your plugin every time you compile your main grails project.

There may be other ways too.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to make a jar from the plugin and put it into my project's lib folder and include it. This is needed when I push my project to the server I will not add the plugin there too.

Comment: If you are adding jar to the lib then you don't need to add it to the dependencies. Also I did not find this library ("com.ticketbis:groobalize:0.1.12") in maven central :http://search.maven.org

Comment: Yes you have to build it yourself. I created the jar as described above and put it to the lib folder. The problem is that eclipse did not find any dependencies. How do you solve this?

Comment: Are you able to compile the project outside of eclipse. try running grails clean / compile from command line.